# Garmin Edge 520, strange conflict

Tags: garmin, heart-rate

[image][image]

I am getting at the same time these two opposite results:
1. WARNIG: Heart rate too high. Maximum heart rate 148
2. INDICATION: Heart rate 134.
Of course 134 is lower.
Why does it happen?

Comment: Check the heart rate settings in the Garmin Connect App or alternatively turn off the High Heart Rate warning

Comment: Thank you for your answer but actually , I think, garmin connect has nothing to do with the device's indications. On the other hand If I don't use at all the device I will have no false indications at all...

Comment: What are you using to measure HR, if it's a strap they rely on being fairly tight to get accurate readings. As for the HR settings they will be set somewhere either on the device or the App its using. I use Garmin myself so I know all the settings can be controlled via Garmin Connect along with customised HR Zones.

Comment: Since when do you get it? I've got the same thing from 2-3 days ago, after their latest update. My guess is a bug in that update. The system seems to respond quicker to spikes in HR that don't show on the display.

Comment: I went today to "garmin service", after inspecting my settings, they said that this  happens maybe because I inserted my own working zones, they set back to default these zones, now I wait to see how it behaves.